# Using additional palettes beyond primary, secondary and error

Tags: material-ui

I can create a theme and replace the default palette like this:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    primary: {
        main: '#aa2222',
    },
    extra: {
        main: '#22aa22',
    },
});
```

This automatically sets `theme.primary.light` and `theme.primary.dark`.  However it does not set the equivalent light and dark values for the `extra` object.

Is there a way to do this for custom elements like `extra` without having to manually calculate the RGB values?  Or am I limited to only `primary`, `secondary`, and `error` getting calculated automatically?

Answer (score 4):

Worked this one out.  This is added on to the end of the code in the question above:

```js
theme.palette.augmentColor(theme.palette.extra, 500, 300, 700);
```

The three numeric parameters are the `mainShade`, `lightShade` and `darkShade` values.  These are the ones used for the default palettes:

```js
augmentColor(primary, 500, 300, 700);
augmentColor(secondary, 'A400', 'A200', 'A700');
augmentColor(error, 500, 300, 700);
```

I think they are there so you can tweak how much the colours are lightened or darkened in case the default isn't readable enough.